# split between 2 pattern in html tag

Tags: php, split

I have a html tag like this

```
<img src="ngakak.gif" title="ngakak" />
```

and I want to split the tag with 2 pattern, they are `title=` and `/>`
. then will result the array like this:

```
Array
 (
     [0] => <img src="ngakak.gif"
     [1] => "ngakak"
 )
```

I want the splitting of 2 patterns worked direct in one regex.
how do this with preg_split ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to extract the title element from all img tags?

```
preg_match_all('/< *[img][^>]*title *= *["']{0,1}([^"'>]*)/',$content,$matches);
```